# Managing temp files in web development

Tags: django

I have a question regarding web architecture. I planning to build a website for uploading photos(This is a personal project). Users can upload multiple photos by zipping and uploading it. Photos can be any resolution while uploading but once basic processing is complete, all photos will stored in a standard resolution JPEG format.
Once zipped photos are uncompressed, they will be presented to the user in a web page as thumbnails, where users can do their last touch-ups (Once photos are saved, no modifications are allowed). 
My question is this, how can I refer the original file when the user select the thumbnails. How can I best associate the temp file with the thumbnail presented. I know I can store the image in a DB and use it, but the original file will be their only till the user save the images and once it saved it will be standard size image.

Even though I am using python/django, I think this is a general web programming question.

thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly reasonable to have a `temp_file_location` type attribute (or even model) and store the intermediate files in a temporary place. Cron jobs or the like can than be used to clean up both the filesystem and the database.